# How to run custom behavior on new releases on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, devops

I want to implement the following behavior: Whenever there's a new release in my repo on GitHub, build the project, then post it on Slack with a changelog that contains all commits since the last release. This seemed to me like a relatively simple task that would be fairly well-supported.

So I looked in continuous integration tools like CircleCI, Jenkins, and TeamCity, none of which seem to support this functionality natively.

Is there any tool that does this out of the box? If not, what would be the best environment to implement this in? Is a CI tool the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish what you're looking for regardless of the CI tool using git tags. First add a git tag to your commit every time you make a release, then during each build run the following and send the output to slack

```
git log <last_released_tag>..HEAD
```

Edit: Here's an untested example using jenkins pipelines relying on [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Slack+Plugin) slack plugin for jenkins

```
node mynode {
   def mytag
   def mychangelog
   mytag = sh (git describe --abbrev=0).trim()
   mychangelong = sh(git log ${mytag}..HEAD).trim()
   slackSend channel: '#mychannel', color: 'good', message: '${mychangelog}', teamDomain: 'mydomain', token: 'mytoken'
}
```

Comment: Of course. My question is about automating this process, so that whenever there's a new release the built project is automatically posted to Slack with the changelog `git log` can generate. Doing it locally is simple

Comment: I provided a jenkins example above. I've done similar things with rake in travis CI as well.